# hp loadrunner using hand coding

Tags: performance, testing, performance-testing, loadrunner

I am new to HP Load Runner and I would like to ask you following questions.

1. Can we perform load testing without using Recordings?
2. Can we perform keyword/data driven testing with HP load Runner using data in CSV/Excel or etc?

I will appreciate if anyone can share examples or methodologies.

Answer (score -1):

You need training and mentoring to understand the class of tools you are working with.   Being socially promoted to a performance testing role by your management without the benefit of skills vetting, training and a mentor is as certain a path of failure as exists in all of software engineering.  This is your management's fault for placing you in this position.

Anything is possible within the bounds of logic and your programming capabilities

Comment: New to something can be, new as a learner not only as employee. your only last line says that it can happen, How, you also have no idea. Thank you very much for your stupid reply.

Comment: Sure, you will have to program an entire custom virtual user to make a transport driven virtual user act as a functional automation keyword driven tool.   As a note, you may want to consider the source of your answer.  With over 14000 questions answered online over the last 20 years on LoadRunner, I can see where you are coming from and the skills and training you need to be successful.  You may blame me, but your management who placed you in this position is the one to blame.  Best of luck in the delivery of value

Comment: I would point you to the advanced section of the LoadRunner Virtual User Generator Users Guide on the creation of virtual users with Visual Studio.  I would also then point you to the standards documentation from the W3C.org for you to construct your own virtual browser through which you can use your keyword driven automation.

Comment: I believe you have some serious issues with my management :-). dude, i am learning performance testing. i mentioned clearly above "Not as an Employee" which means this is something i am exploring personally & to explore anything we dn't need management's approval.

Comment: Only 5-12% of any performance testing engagement involves the tool, any tool.   Someplace where you may want to begin is with the excellently documented benchmarks at TPC.org, particularly the TPC-C benchmark.   From there move to confirm your core skills in programming, architecture, networking, requirements, systems analysis (independent of tool), fault isolation (independent of tool), and in depth understanding of a number of your architectural components.

Comment: The common path to a successful performance tester passes through these three phases: a confirmation of core foundation skills, training and mentoring with a professional for a period of time - often up to a year. The length of mentorship is inversely related to the maturity of your core foundation skills.   The weaker your skills, the longer your period of internship in order to bring those skills together with process and tool in the exercise of a performance testing effort

Comment: The rare exception to the path is when someone has robust, mature skills in almost all foundation areas developed over decades and then they are only looking at a new tool where they are applying existing skills.  Even so, value will be difficult to measure for six-12 weeks in the new role.   Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much for understanding my question correctly. I am coding from last 13+ years and i can understand that such things need core foundation skills and training. I posted this question to know correct directions from experts and to move myself in correct direction based on their guidance. I appreciate your guidance in this regard.

Comment: One more thing, I would like to suggest you to kindly support beginners specially when they come to you with their questions/ideas/approaches, kindly guide them with your experience and expertise instead of making things complex for them which can demotivate to anyone. We all are here to help each other and learn from each other. Also please avoid assumptions (involvement of management in my case). Lot of peoples in this world are self-starter. Thanks for your time, Stay Blessed.